# How do you say "a brush-shop clerk" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, translation

In Japanese would 「筆店の受付」 be how to translate "a brush-shop clerk"　(an employee in an administrative position at a small store that sells all kinds of brushes [probably hair brushes and paint brushes, not only calligraphy supplies])? Is 「受付」 a normal translation for a clerk?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"受{うけ}付{つけ}" usually means "receptionist."

And we usually say "店{てん}員{いん}" for general (= not necessarily administrative) "shop clerk."

While "筆店" makes sense to mean "brush shop" as in -> arimahude.com, many Japanese brush shops seem to prefer calling themselves "筆{ふで}専{せん}門{もん}店{てん}" as in -> fudeya-shop.comor , or more fancy(?) "筆　セレクトショップ" and the like, as in -> kumanofude-selectshop.com .